# Converting comma separated values to separate rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't really have a say on how the tables are designed. I know that this is not a good practice, I am just trying to do my job with the given requirements.

Is there a way in SQL server to convert

```
Name    Mar
ABC     03, 08, 09, 23
DEF     10, 26, 29, 35
```

to

```
Name    Mar
ABC     3
ABC     8
ABC     9
ABC    23
ABC    10
DEF    26
DEF    29
DEF    35
```

Here are the scripts below :

```
create table #tmp 
(Name varchar(50) , Markets varchar(50));        

insert into #tmp
values ('ABC', '03, 08, 09, 23')

insert into #tmp
values ('DEF', '10, 26, 29, 35')
```

I searched online and came up with this solution . but it creates an extra space for some of the strings and for some it doesn't

```
SELECT A.[Name],  
 Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT [Name],  
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([Markets], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  #tmp) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(A);  

Name    String
ABC 03
ABC  08
ABC  09
ABC  23
DEF 10
DEF  26
DEF  29
DEF  35
```

Comment: I wrote a series on splitting strings. The bottom line: avoid it if you can (e.g. don't store those values that way in the first place, or pass them in via TVPs). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings http://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-now-with-less-t-sql

Comment: I dont really have a say on how the strings need to be stored. I know that this is not a good practice. I am just trying to do my job with the given requirements. Please dont downvote  me for that reason.

Comment: I did not down-vote you, just gave you a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have does work, just look closer at your string of values and the output.  You have a space between the comma and the number.

Just put a LTRIM() in there

```
LTRIM(Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')) AS String
```

[Split Functions](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score 0):

this query returns

```
SELECT A.Substance ,
 Split.A.value('.', 'VARCHAR(4000)') AS String  
 FROM  (SELECT Substance, ID, 
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Substance, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  [final_substance]) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(A);
```

issue

XML parsing: line 1, character 20, illegal qualified name character

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)